# translate "percent" in chinese 百分之 or 百分比?

Tags: translation, vocabulary

is there one by the two words above usually used for " percent " ?

or is it usual  to use any of them ?

wenlin software  gives 百分比 as percent.

mdbg dictionary on line gives 百分之   :-)

Comment: what exactly does wenlin say? Users find it hard to believe that wenlin would simply give the equation "percent = 百分比", also do they not have usage examples ?

Comment: Users after having had a look at the wenlin website, find it totally unbelievable that their dictionary would yield such totally unsatisfactory
information.

Comment: @user6065  sorry to answer late.  yes, wenlin gives  百分比 when you are looking for words that contain bai 百
when you are looking at percent in the english dictionary, the software gives 百分之  ！  then you are also right. i like wenlin but it is perfectible :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matter of taste. You want prefix style, use 百分比, as in 五个百分比. Suffix style, use 百分之, as in 百分之五.

百分之 is a sentence pattern, and requires a number. 百分比 is a noun, and also means percentage on its own.

Comment: To judge from usage examples in dictionaries x个百分点 seems more common than x个百分比 , e.g. 现代汉语词典 has 同前一年相比，通货膨胀率减少三个百分点,for 百分比 现代汉语词典 only has this example showing use as "percentage" ：某班５０个学生当中有２０个是女生，这一班中女生所占的百分比就是４０％ (entries in 应用汉语词典 similar）。However x个百分比 can be found in BKRS: 新生人数比去年增加了两个百分比。 The number of new students, compared to last year's, has increased by two percent. Also jukuu has maximum number of 100 examples for x个百分点 (x%), and although there also are 100 examples for 百分比, they all seem to be in the sense of "percentage"（of course 百分之x is the usual equivalent of x%）

Comment: quoted examples (involving comparison,increase or decrease) may suggest usage range of 百分点,百分比 (for %) may be narrower than that of 百分之,e.g.plain ＂x% of something＂ might only be 百分之x的某事，see
jukuu：百分之八十的领土是山,百分之七十的士兵,百分之的酒精，百分之的谷物蒸馏，百分之五十四的选票

Comment: 百分之 seems to be more used than 百分比. Over 12 million results on Google against 2 million.

Comment: This most likely does not include instances of "%" in Chinese texts, which are still read "百分之＂.How often 百分比 as part of x个百分比 to mean percent
also seems relevant, and googling "个百分比" yielding 688000 hits of course does not mean it is used that way the indicated number of times, which according to above may only be a tiny fraction.

Answer (score 2):

百分比 is percentage
百分之 is percent

for example:
one percent = 百分之一
five percentages = 五个百分比

Answer (score 2):

‘五个百分比’ 是错误的。虽然大家能听懂您的意思，但是感觉上很别扭。

5%，读作 ‘百分之五 ’；

‘五个百分点’ ，意思相同，在口语中很常用。

1%、2%、30%这3个百分比中，其中一个也可以说“3成”，这个百分比就是30%  。

这期彩票 我 百分之百 会中！到时我请你们去吃牛排。你们喜欢几成熟的？

我要8成熟的(80%)。

我要8分熟的(80%)。

我要全熟的（100%）。

我要熟透了的(100%)。

Answer (score 1):

"百分比" means percentage and can be used alone as a noun. "百分之" can only be used as a prefix, and the result is a specific percentage, e.g. 1%, 2%.

The expression 1% etc are pronounced as 百分之..., that could give you a sense.

For example: A 占 B的百分比是多少？ 百分之一（1%）。

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way: % in 国语 (Taiwanese Mandarin) is pronounced pa1.

You can basically take any number: 10 (shi2) and add % (pa1) on the end and you're done.

http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%25

Answer (score -1):

https://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=worddict&wdrst=1&wdqb=e%3Apercent

The answer is there. 三七開定論, 百分率

Comment: Please add the information here. Links can die.